# NotReadablePropertyException when tomcat startup with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

When my springboot application startup, I have the following exception. I didn't found where is problem, if someone has an idea... thanks by advance

```
2015-05-18 14:50:49,313 DEBUG c.q.q.Application:50 - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.6.RELEASE
2015-05-18 14:50:51,848 DEBUG o.j.logging:33 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
2015-05-18 14:50:51,991 DEBUG c.q.q.c.AsyncConfiguration:36 - Creating Async Task Executor
2015-05-18 14:50:52,126  INFO c.q.q.Application:60 - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
2015-05-18 14:50:52,752 DEBUG c.q.q.c.MetricsConfiguration:71 - Registring JVM gauges
2015-05-18 14:50:54,870 ERROR o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatStarter:62 - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
2015-05-18 14:50:54,914  WARN o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.qwam.qes.Application.main(Application.java:84) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: : Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'token[key]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'token[key]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'token[key]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'token[key]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'token[key]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'token[key]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'token[key]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'token[key]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

this is my application class:

```
@ComponentScan (basePackages = { "com.test" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
@Domain(basePackages = { "com.test.domain" })
public class Application {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() throws IOException {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
        } else {
            log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);

        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);

        // Check if the selected profile has been set as argument.
        // if not the development profile will be added
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);

    }

         /**
     * Set a default profile if it has not been set
     *
     * @param app
     * @param source
     */
    private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active")) {
            app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<String> responseBodyConverter() {
        return new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator lazyInitAutoProxyCreator() {
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator autoProxyCreator = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        TargetSourceCreator[] targetSourceCreators = {lazyInitTargetSourceCreator()};
        autoProxyCreator.setCustomTargetSourceCreators(targetSourceCreators);
        return autoProxyCreator;
    }

    @Bean
    public LazyInitTargetSourceCreator lazyInitTargetSourceCreator() {
        return new LazyInitTargetSourceCreator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Application` starter class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `@Configuration` annotation to your `Application` class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan (basePackages = { "com.test" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
@Domain(basePackages = { "com.test.domain" })
public class Application {        
       //some code
}
```